# sort (usort) on WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, usort

Can't seem to get this running no matter what:

```
$args = array(...);
$unitsQuery = new WP_Query($args);

function customCompare($a, $b)
{
    return strcasecmp($a->post_title,$b->post_title);
}

$unitsQuery->posts = usort($unitsQuery->posts, 'customCompare');

if( $unitsQuery->have_posts() ) {
    while($unitsQuery->have_posts()) : $unitsQuery->the_post();?>

    <div><?php the_title(); ?></div>

    <?php endwhile;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Everything works absolutely fine without calling the sort. I REALLY need to run a custom sort after the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `usort()` only returns `true` or `false`, so with this line:

```
$unitsQuery->posts = usort($unitsQuery->posts, 'customCompare');
```

you're overriding the posts. Change it to:

```
usort( $unitsQuery->posts, 'customCompare' );
```

I wonder why you must use `usort` instead of the `orderby` parameter of `WP_Query` or the `posts_orderby` filter.

Comment: Thanks Birgire, now I realize why I was getting "1" when printing $query->posts after assigning it. The reason is that the data I want to use in the sort is not in the posts. The posts only have a pointer (id) of a taxonomy term (custom fields), but I want to sort the posts by the Alphabetic order of the terms. (I use the sort inside wp_query whenever possible since it's much easier, but don't think it would be possible with this one). All sorted now thanks!